# Javascript object not working when i changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a program for highlight all words in a page that searched.
It working fine when I do like this

```
var high = "<span class='highlighted'>hello</span>";
document.getElementById("inputText").innerHTML = inputText.replace(/\kumar/g, high);
```

it replace all kumar name with hello highligheted..

But it is static we can't change `kumar` at run time
so i want to change like this

```
var high = "<span class='highlighted'>hello</span>";
var kk='kumar';
document.getElementById("inputText").innerHTML = inputText.replace(/\kk/g, high);
```

but this doesn't work. It doesn't change `kumar` word....

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Comment: Java is not Javascript ! Please be careful when you add the tags in your question.

Comment: You need `new RegExp(text)` to construct dynamic ones

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson & @ZouZou thanks sir for tell me java is not javascript..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RegExp` constructor

```
var high = "<span class='highlighted'>hello</span>";
var kk='kumar';
document.getElementById("inputText").innerHTML = inputText.replace(new RegExp(kk, 'g'), high);
```

Pay attention to escaping because what you pass to the constructor is a literal string.
For more info you just need google it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `RegExp` literal you can use the `RegExp` constructor.

```
var yourVar = "pattern (to replace)";
var re = new RegExp(yourVar, "g");
```

and then:

```
var high = "<span class='highlighted'>hello</span>";
document.getElementById("inputText").innerHTML = inputText.replace(re, high);
```